# On-screen menu pops up when pressing numpad 5 for long

Tags: keyboard, multiple-monitors

I am running a program called WISP (matlab-based experiment running software) on a computer with 4 external monitors. When I press 5 for a long time during an experiment, an on-screen menu pops up on one of the monitors (not the main display) that I can't get rid off. It looks like this:
[screenshot of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLd06.png)

The computer is a dual-boot mac where we use the PC side, and the monitor that the menu pops up on is a Dell screen. I tried switching out the keyboard thinking it may be the keyboard but that didn't help. 
Any insight into what may cause this? Or, how to get rid of it once it popped up? I tried esc, end, enter, 0 and none work.

Comment: Judging from your image (which BTW is very small; a larger, clearer image might help), it looks like a brightness or contrast control, so I would guess it's a feature of the monitor. What is the monitor model?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the problem is actually with mplayer, the video player that the program uses https://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html . The default is that  5 is the shortcut for adjusting hue, so I think that's it.

Comment: Makes sense, glad you found it.

Comment: You can post and accept your own answer.